Azure API Management access from Microsoft Fabric - handling IP restrictions
I'm trying to access an Azure API Management instance from Microsoft Fabric (Notebook). The API has IP restrictions configured that block incoming requests.
Current setup:

I have an Azure API Management instance with IP restrictions enabled
I need to consume this API from Microsoft Fabric dataflows
Direct access is blocked due to the IP restrictions

What I've considered

IP whitelisting(Not sure what IPs to whitelist? Do not want to whitelist a whole regions range)
Private Link/Private Endpoints(Not sure if this is the right path for this type of communication?)

Question:
What is the recommended approach to securely connect Microsoft Fabric to an IP-restricted Azure API Management instance?

Have you tried any other approach so far? @Jostein Sortland

@Jahnavi No, as this are the only viable as I see it?

After investigating several approaches, I found a robust solution that maintains security principles while staying aligned with Microsoft's architecture patterns.
Solution:
I implemented an Azure Function that acts as a middleware/proxy between Microsoft Fabric and the API Management instance. Here's how it works:
Architecture:

Azure Function acts as an intermediary service
Microsoft Fabric connects to the Azure Function through managed endpoints
Azure Function forwards requests to APIM
Only the Azure Function's static IP needs to be whitelisted in APIM
The solution is future-proof, and the function can probably be moved to fabric in the future, sine AF is in preview for fabric.

Hope this helps others facing similar challenges!

Fabric currently only supports Managed Private Endpoints in Spark and Eventstream.  I thought you were using Dataflows.  Did you switch from Dataflows to a Spark Notebook (which has a lot of other benefits if you can already write code)?

Yes, using notebook, edited my question now.

You'll need to use an On Prem Data Gateway or a VNet Data gateway to access IP-restricted endpoints.  In Fabric outbound Private Endpoints only work with Spark.

See my answer above
